# How to get paging on IEnumerator object

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have list of rows stored in object IEnumerator.

I need to display the row items as paging so that On Next button click it would display next item from the object while on pressing Previous button it should display the previous row.

My failed attempted code below...

```
    Dim en As IEnumerator
    Dim row As DataRow
    Dim dt As DataTable dt = loadTips() // return datatable
    en = dt.Rows.GetEnumerator()

 Protected Sub btn_nxt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_nxt.Click
        While en.MoveNext
            row = en.Current
            Response.Write(row(0))
        End While
    End Sub

   Protected Sub btn_pre_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_pre.Click
        ' code to move previous row
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the current page and  simplify the enumerator to just those items.

`Skip` and `Take` are helper methods to simplify this.

Comment: Sorry but what you mean by "You need to store the current page "?

Comment: By default you are showing page 1 (or 0 depending on convention). You need to somehow get that page to the server so it knows which page to show.